# Is it possible to embed a Surveymonkey form to my website that shows the full form without scroll?

Tags: javascript, height, width, embed, surveymonkey

The only option I can see is to choose the width and height on survey monkey and it generates a JS code to host.

This is the code I'm being given (I've removed my actually form url name for privacy reasons):

```
<script>(function(t,e,n,o){var s,c,i;t.SMCX=t.SMCX||[],e.getElementById(o)||    (s=e.getElementsByTagName(n),c=s[s.length-1],i=e.createElement(n),i.type="text/javascript",i.async=!0,i.id=o,i.src=["https:"===location.protocol?"https://":"http://","FORM.js"].join(""),c.parentNode.insertBefore(i,c))})(window,document,"script","smcx-sdk");</script>
```

Here's an idea of what result I'm getting

[image]

I want to be able to have the form look like its part of the webpage and not an embedded box that scrolls.

Is there a way to force this?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

**SOLVED:** Found alternative work around

Comment: u could share that workaround for others who are facing the same problem...